# dimension of fiber of variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a problem proving the fiber dimension theorem:
For a morphism between irreducible $k$ varieties, there is a nonempty open subset $U \subset Y$ such that for every $q \in U$ the fiber over $q$ has pure dimension $\operatorname{dim} X - \operatorname{dim} Y$.

In Ravi Vakil FOAG this is posed as an exerise 11.4.B, and I tried to prove $\operatorname{dim} X - \operatorname{dim} Y \geq \operatorname{codim}_{\pi^{-1}(q)} p$ as follows: $\operatorname{codim}_X p \leq \operatorname{codim}_Y q + \operatorname{codim}_{\pi^{-1}(q)} p$ and

$\operatorname{dim}_X p + \operatorname{codim}_X p = \operatorname{dim} X, \operatorname{dim}_Y q + \operatorname{codim}_Y q = \operatorname{dim} Y$

so it suffices to show

$\operatorname{coht} p \leq \operatorname{coht} q$

where the points are regarded as prime ideals of $X = \operatorname{Spec} A, Y = \operatorname{Spec} B$.

But $B/q \rightarrow A/p$ is injective, and therefore $\operatorname{dim} B/q \leq \operatorname{dim} A/p $ by considering transcendence degree.

Here is my problem. I got the converse inequality. Where I went wrong? And how can I prove it?

Comment: You are talking about a morphism and we have to guess what the domain and codomain are.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez♦ Sorry, I couldn't get at it.

Comment: Here, you are choosing $p$ to be the generic point of an irreducible component of $\pi^{-1}(q),$ so $\text{codim}_{\pi^{-1}(q)}(p) = 0$ right?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking this question. It is nice to know that I am not the only one who is stuck on this. Let me try to attempt answering this, but I hope that someone corrects it, if I make any wrong remark.

Following the remarks Vakil makes in 11.4.B in his notes, we are in the situation where we have $\pi : X = \text{Spec}(A) \rightarrow \text{Spec}(B) = Y$ induced by an inclusion $B \hookrightarrow A$ of integral domains that are finitely generated over a field $k$. Fix any $y \in Y$.

We use what Vakil proves later which is the existence of a nonempty distinguished open $U$ in $X$ such that $\pi^{-1}(U) \rightarrow U$ factors as $\pi^{-1}(U) \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{m-n}_{k} \times_{k} U \rightarrow U$ where the first map is finite and surjective and the second one is the projection map. Since $U$ is distinguished open, we may write $U = \text{Spec}(B_{g})$. Then we can write down the given factorization as $\text{Spec}(A_{\phi(g)}) \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{m-n}_{B_{g}} \rightarrow \text{Spec}(B_{g})$ where $\phi : B \rightarrow A$ denotes the corresponding ring map of $\pi : X \rightarrow Y$. Thus, the corresponding ring map $B_{g} \rightarrow A_{\phi(g)}$ must factor as $B_{g} \rightarrow B_{g}[t_{1}, \dots, t_{m-n}] \rightarrow A_{\phi(g)}$. Since $B_{g}$ has fraction field $B_{(0)}$, by considering transcendence degree, we have $\dim(B_{g}) = \dim(B)$. Similarly, we have $\dim(A_{\phi(g)}) = \dim(A)$. This lets us replace $B_{g}$ with $B$ and $A_{g}$ with $A$ in our proof. Hence, we are working with $B \rightarrow B[t_{1}, \dots, t_{m-n}] \rightarrow A$.

Fix $y \in U$. We want to show that $\pi^{-1}(y)$ is of pure dimension $m - n$ where $m = \dim(A)$ and $n = \dim(Y)$.  Note that by convention we give $\pi^{-1}(y)$ a scheme structure by taking the spectrum of $R = \kappa(y) \otimes_{B} A$, and this is a finitely generated algebra over the residue field $\kappa(y)$. Thus, for any minimal prime $\mathfrak{h} \subset R$, we have $\dim(R) = \dim(R/\mathfrak{h})$, which shows that $\dim(\pi^{-1}(y)) = \dim(R)$ is of pure dimension of some number. Thus, we only need to check $\dim(\pi^{-1}(y)) = m - n$.

Applying base change over $\kappa(y)$ to the factorization $\pi^{-1}(U) \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{m-n}_{k} \times U \rightarrow U$, we get $\pi^{-1}(y) \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{m-n}_{\kappa(y)} \rightarrow \text{Spec}(\kappa(y))$, and the first map is still finite and surjective by 9.4.B (d) and 9.4.D of Vakil's notes.

**Step 1**. We first show $\dim(\pi^{-1}(y)) \leq m - n$.

Let $Z = \overline{\{x\}} \cap \pi^{-1}(y) \subset \pi^{-1}(y) = \text{Spec}(\kappa(y) \otimes_{B} A)$ be any irreducible component. Then we may write $Z = \text{Spec}((\kappa(y) \otimes_{B} A)/\mathfrak{p}')$ where $\mathfrak{p}'$ represents $x$ in the fiber. Ring-wise, we have $\kappa(y) \hookrightarrow \kappa(y)[t_{1}, \dots, t_{m-n}]/\mathfrak{q}' \hookrightarrow (\kappa(y) \otimes_{B} A)/\mathfrak{p}'$, where $\mathfrak{q}'$ is the image of $x$ in $\mathbb{A}^{m-n}_{\kappa(y)}$ under $\pi^{-1}(y) \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{m-n}_{\kappa(y)}$. Since the second inclusion is finite, it must preserve dimension, so

$\begin{align*}\dim(\pi^{-1}(y)) &= \dim(Z)\\ &= \dim((\kappa(y) \otimes_{B} A)/\mathfrak{p}')\\ &= \dim(\kappa(y)[t_{1}, \dots, t_{m-n}]/\mathfrak{q}')\\ &= m-n-\text{ht}(\mathfrak{q'}) \\&\leq m-n,\end{align*}$

as desired.

**Step 2**. It remains to show that $\dim(\pi^{-1}(y)) \geq m-n.$

We use the finite surjection $\pi^{-1}(y) \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{A}^{m-n}_{\kappa(y)}.$ Consider $(0) \in \text{Spec}(\kappa(y)[t_{1}, \dots, t_{m-n}]) = \mathbb{A}^{m-n}_{\kappa(y)},$ the generic point. Since the map is surjective there must be some $x \in \pi^{-1}(y)$ mapping into $(0)$. Writing $\pi^{-1}(y) = \text{Spec}(R)$ and denoting $x = \mathfrak{p},$ the map corresponds to a finite ring map $\kappa(y)[t_{1}, \dots, t_{m-n}] \rightarrow R$ and this map pulls $\mathfrak{p}$ back to $(0)$. Hence we get a finite ring map $\kappa(y)[t_{1}, \dots, t_{m-n}] \rightarrow R/\mathfrak{p}$ that pulls $(0)$ to $(0)$, so we must have a finite extension $\kappa(y)[t_{1}, \dots, t_{m-n}] \hookrightarrow R/\mathfrak{p},$ and since finite extension does not change the dimension, we must have $m-n = \dim(R/\mathfrak{p}) \leq \dim(R) = \dim(\pi^{-1}(y)),$ as desired.

**Remark**. I am quite bothered by the fact that Step 2 does not use Vakil's hint in his book. I tried to work out that way, but I could not come up with any sounding proof. If anyone finds a mistake in Step 2 or has a different answer, I would love to see it!

Comment: On your 'Applying base change over ...' part of the proof: 
I not understand how you conclude here that $\pi^{-1}(y)$ is
*equidimensional* or *of pure dimension*. That is that for *every* minimal prime 
$\mathfrak{h} \subset \kappa(y) \otimes_{B} A$ we have
$\dim(R) = \dim(R/\mathfrak{h})$. Could you elaborate this argument?

Comment: @Gil I'm a little late to this thread since I just began Vakil this year, but I don't actually think you need steps 1 & 2 to show that the dimensions are equal — the claim should actually follow from that last paragraph right before Step 1. 

If you look at the bottom of p. 310 at §11.2.7, Vakil makes note of how Noether Normalization + Exercise 11.1.E allow you to conclude that if there exists a finite surjective $k$-morphism $X \to \mathbb{A}^n_k$, then $\dim X = \dim \mathbb{A}^n_k$. In the case of this problem, we simply have $k = \kappa(y)$